# DimpleJS. Y axis values in percentages

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, dimple.js

[image: Get y axis in percentage]
`I am plotting Vertical Grouped Bar Chart` from a csv file which contains Discount, Rating and Clicked. The data is csv is like 55,2,1 and 40,5,0 etc. Here the first value(55,40) are the discounts, (2,5) rating and 1 and 0 correspond to `clicked` and `not clicked` respectively. On plotting the chart with following code.

```
  var svg2 = dimple.newSvg("#discountContainer", 590, 400);
    d3.csv("/svm1000.csv", function (data) {
      var myChart2 = new dimple.chart(svg2, data);
      myChart2.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 330)
      myChart2.addCategoryAxis("x", ["rating", "action"]);
      var y = myChart2.addMeasureAxis("y", "discount");
      //y.tickFormat = "%";
      myChart2.addSeries("action", dimple.plot.bar);
      myChart2.addLegend(65, 10, 510, 20, "right");
      myChart2.draw();
    });
```

The problem is I want to represent y axis in percentage in `multiple of 10, like 0%, 10%, 20% .. 100%`. Right now the y axis values are like `0,2k,4k,6k...20k`. So how to represent y axis in percentage.

Comment: this isn't D3 is it ?

Comment: its in dimpleJS which is built on D3

Comment: ok if it is anything like D3 you use tickvalues(), loads of examples online

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is old, so this answer may not help you, but for others facing similar requirements this might be helpful.

dimple.js provide method to have percentage series

```
myChart2.addPctAxis("y", "discount");
```

but remember you can't create both Value and Percentage in same axis, you might need to have dual axis graph

```
var x = myChart2.addCategoryAxis("x", ["rating", "action"]);
var y1 = myChart2.addPctAxis("y", "discount");
var y2 = myChart2.addMeasureAxis("y", "amount"); // the field with value ranges 1000...
```

also you don't able to use grouped bar chart; for axis 1 use bar chart and for axis 2 use line or vice versa like

```
myChart2.addSeries("action", dimple.plot.bar, [x, y1]);
myChart2.addSeries("action", dimple.plot.line, [x, y2]);
```